# how to auto-login to site with Windows Authentication if computer is not part of domain?

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, credentials-manager, single-sign-on

we have intranet site with Windows Authentication enabled. Users can auto-login fine - if their computer is part of the domain. But we have one dev computer which is not part of the domain for business reasons. It has Win 10 Pro. We have successfully configured it via `Windows Credentials Manager` to connect to intranet SQLSERVER using AD, or to file shares - again, using AD credentials:

[image]

but I cannot figure out if it's possible to do the same to allow seamless login to intranet sites. Basically to avoid popups like this:

[image]

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: WIA requires that the client is part of a domain. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication

Answer (score 0):

actually, turns out it's possible. If you add that website into your `Local Intranet` zone in `IE -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Security` tab AND add exact URL (with port number if needed) to the Windows Credentials manager then it works. Tested on TeamCity with windows login + another intranet website with Windows Authentication enabled on IIS.